# Let p be an odd prime, q the smallest quadratic non residue (mod p). Prove q is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity, quadratic-residues

So I have this problem;

Let p be an odd prime and let q be the smallest positive integer which is a quadratic non residue (mod p). Prove q is a prime.

So what I know is that, since q is the smallest positive integer which is a quadratic non residue (mod p) then Legendre symbol (q|p) = -1 = q^((p-1)/2) (mod p). But I'm not sure if this is the correct direction with what I am doing since I can't concluding anything (obviously) from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if $q$ is composite, it can be written as $ab$ where $a < q$ and $b < q$.
Can $a$ and $b$ both be quadratic residues mod $p$?

Comment: So then Legendre Symbol (q|p) = (ab|p) = (a|p)*(b|p). In other words, one is -1 and the other is 1, since q is a quadratic non residue? How does this tell us q must be prime though?

Comment: Because if $a$ or $b$ is a nonresidue, $q$ wasn't the smallest nonresidue.

Comment: Oh thank you! Slipped right passed me.

Comment: @JonathanMckibbin Did Robert's answer meet your needs? You should accept it!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of contradiction we assume that q is composite. That is, q can be written in the form q = ab, where a,b∈Z with a,b < q. By rules of Legendre Symbols, we know that (q|p) = (ab|p) = (a|p) ∙ (b|p) = -1. That is one of (a|p), (b|p) = -1, and the other is equivalent to 1. That is whichever is equivalent to -1 is a quadratic non residue (mod p) smaller than q, a contradiction. Therefore, q must be prime.